# A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to run the video from https site, i am getting this exception after setting the source of the media element and invoke `mediaelement.play`.

Here is my code,

```
 <MediaElement Name="mediaElement1" LoadedBehavior="Manual" >


  mediaElement1.Source = new Uri("https://f60b7719060a37f20253-4343910d3bf76239b8a83e4f56d17dc5.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/mov-2015-05-25-22-01-53-a0731841b309b95209417646a2559d51077345cb.mp4");

                //mediaElement1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
                mediaElement1.Play();
```

A first chance exception of type

> 'System.NullReferenceException'

occurred in `PresentationCore.dll`

Any help please?. Struggling for the whole day, googled but no luck.

I achieved the same using webclient, downloaded the file to temp folder and trying to play from that location. But its working in my machine, in some machine due to lack of permission its not working.

Here is my workaround

```
    private readonly WebClient _webClient = new WebClient();
  private string fileName ;
private string tempPath ;

 private void BtnPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();

                _webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += webClient_DownloadFileCompleted;

 var uri = newnew Uri("https://f60b7719060a37f20253-4343910d3bf76239b8a83e4f56d17dc5.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/mov-2015-05-25-22-01-53-a0731841b309b95209417646a2559d51077345cb.mp4", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                        fileName = tempPath + uri.Segments[1];
if (!File.Exists(fileName))
                            _webClient.DownloadFileAsync(uri, fileName);
                        else
                        {
                           mediaElement.Source = new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Absolute);

                            if (mediaElement.LoadedBehavior != MediaState.Play)
                                mediaElement.Play();

                        }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {


            }

        }
 void webClient_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
                mediaElement.Source = new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Absolute);
                if (mediaElement.LoadedBehavior != MediaState.Play)
                    mediaElement.Play();

        }
```

Its not working in some machine which(temp folder) dont have write permission
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No more stacktrace than that?

Comment: Well, *something* is null.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. this is the exception i am getting, no stack trace

Comment: tempPath = = Path.GetTempPath();?

Comment: sorry copy paste mistake, i did correction

Comment: this is the inner exception  at System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayerState.OpenMedia(Uri source)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayerState.SetSource(Uri source)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer.Open(Uri source)
   at System.Windows.Controls.AVElementHelper.HandleStateChange()
   at WPF3D.WPFMusic.BtnPlay_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in